# Back button in UINavigationBar is opening the current view itself

Tags: uitableview, uisearchbar, xcode-storyboard

(1). I just added UISearchBar in UITableView in Storyboard. When I click the cell from default UITableView, it goes to details view and I can go back to default UITableView by clicking Back button in navigation bar. It is correct.

> ```
> UITableView(BooksViewController with title "Books")
> -Item 1(Selected)
> -Item 2
> -Item 3
>
> DetailsView(BookDetailsViewController)
> Books(Back button in navigation bar)
> Item 1(View Title)
> ```

(2). The problem is when I click the cell from searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView, it goes to details view and I can't go back to default UITableView by clicking Back button in navigation bar. The program ends with the following error.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't add self as subview'
```

> ```
> UITableView(BooksViewController with title "Books")
> Search Results
> Item 1(Selected)
> Item 3
>
> DetailsView(BookDetailsViewController)
> Item 1(Back button in navigation bar)
> Item 1(View Title)
> ```

You may notice Back button title is showing the view title in case (2) and can't go back to previous view properly. How do I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem by tracing segue action in console. I don't need to do my own segue action in cell selection. It makes app to open details view twice. That's why Back button is going back the detail view it self. By removing [self performSegueWithIdentifier], it works now.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"segueSongsToSong" sender: self];
   }
}
```

to

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
}
```